# View Filter by Request URI

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want to create a new view to filter several URIs there. Some URI like:

`/edu/class`

`/edu/new-class`

`/edu/grades`

which one is the right one:

`\/edu/class|\/edu/new\-class|\/edu/grades`

or

`\/edu\/class|\/edu\/new\-class|\/edu\/grades`

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Neither of these is correct. You would instead use a pattern like this:

```
/edu/(class|new-class|grades)
```

In this expression, the parentheses `()` contain a list of alternate matches, with each match separated by a pipe character `|`.

Alternately, you could also write

```
/edu/class|/edu/new-class|/edu/grades
```

... but the first example is easier to extend.

For Google Analytics, you can find more information on regular expressions here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en